# Android: What is the best HTTP library for uploading images to server?

Tags: java, android, performance, http, cloud

There many libraries available, but which is better for image uploading ?
Does anyone knows which library instagram uses ?

I have tried volley before, but it is not good.

Here are the populars ones"

**AndroidAsync** - https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

**android-async-http** - https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

**okhttp** - https://github.com/square/okhttp

**http-request** - https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

**android-volley** - https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

**ion** - https://github.com/koush/ion

**retrofit**- https://github.com/square/retrofit

**Bolts-Android**- https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you think Instagram was build using java libraries... you'll be wrong. Most of those social networks use Python, Ruby and other multi platform languages. The best library depends on you and what you need. Try different ones and see how it goes.

Comment: I think he's referring to the Instagram Android app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The library you mentioned are very different in nature. They can be more or less grouped like this

**Socket level API:**

This includes

- AndroidAsync
- okhttp
- HttpClient
- HttpURLConnection

These are very low level API, which built around how to send packages through Socket and optimization.

Among these, android 23 now uses okhttp internally, and okhttp has been around for a very long time, which makes it my personal favourite for Socket level API.

**Higher level API:**

These API are built to help developer to develop faster with ease of use, it usually works as a wrapper on Socket level API. Here is the relation between them

- Retrofit - *okhttp*
- android-async-http - *HttpClient*
- ion - *AndroidAsync*
- Bolts-Android - not sure what it base on
- Volley* - depending on API level, HttpURLConnection / HttpClient in system library

**Image Loading API:**

Volley is a special API, it is a High Level API, but it has another usage, which is Image Loading. These type of API includes the following:

- Volley
- Picasso
- Fresco
- Glide

**Conclusion:**

For your scenario, I believe you are looking for a High level API. However, it would be difficult to suggest the **Best** API, it would depends on usage and personal preferences.

Volley WAS*  not a very good as a *High level API*, several functionality are not included, e.g. Https, data stream upload. I would suggest you to start seeking the best library for your project, starting with **Retrofit**, **ion** and **Bolts**.

*I haven't tried Volley since I used it on the first year when it is released, it could have changed.

**Edit:**

I have just installed **Instagram** app and checked their `OPEN SOURCE LIBRARIES` section, they have included **android-async-http**, which is likely to mean they used it for HTTP requests.

Comment: Additional info for you: I have just installed Instagram app and checked their `OPEN SOURCE LIBRARIES` section, they have included **android-async-http**, which is likely to mean they used it for HTTP requests. You are actually check this info by yourself.

Comment: I have experience uploading image by Retofit 1.9. And to be better integration, I recommend that library.

Comment: But he is asking about UPLOADING the image to server, LOADING image is totally different